# 'module' object has no attribute 'views' django error

Tags: python, django

If I import django's built in login view as in following code

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'login/$', login, name='login'),
)
```

every thing works fine, but if I'll include it in following way

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import auth

urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'login/$', auth.views.login, name='login'),
)
```

I get the following error

```
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'views'
```

what is really bothering me is in another project I am importing it the second way and it is working fine. Does anyone know what's going on over here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the second project you've probably already imported the `auth.views` module before  calling `auth.views.login`. Python stitches your imported modules when it can.

For example, this will work

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.views import login #or from django.contrib.auth import views
>>> from django.contrib import auth

>>> auth.views.login
<function login at 0x02C37C30>
```

The first import doesn't even have to mention the `login` view. This will also work.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.views import logout
...
#then import auth.views.login
```

The following won't because python does not know of the `views` module since it isn't registered in `auth.__init__.py`

```
>>> from django.contrib import auth

>>> auth.views.login
...
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'views'
```

Comment: It seems like I missed a very important point while learning python. I cannot remember reading it anywhere that "You cannot import a package and then later on call package.module.function() later on." No body seems to talk about this restriction of packages anywhere.

Comment: @Nik I also had to learn the heard way, but it's only because I hadn't properly understood how importation works in python. Once you understand it, it's pretty obvious why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

In the first import (`from django.contrib.auth.views import login`), the dot syntax is traversing the module hierarchy.  In the urlpattern access (`auth.views.login`), the dot-syntax is doing property (ie. class) lookup. From my shell_plus, you can see that "auth" doesn't have a views property.

```
In [1]: from django.contrib import auth

In [2]: auth.<TAB FOR COMPLETION>
auth.BACKEND_SESSION_KEY      auth.load_backend
auth.ImproperlyConfigured     auth.login
auth.PermissionDenied         auth.logout
auth.REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME      auth.models
auth.SESSION_KEY              auth.re
auth.authenticate             auth.rotate_token
auth.forms                    auth.settings
auth.get_backends             auth.signals
auth.get_permission_codename  auth.tokens
auth.get_user                 auth.user_logged_in
auth.get_user_model           auth.user_logged_out
auth.hashers                  auth.user_login_failed
auth.import_by_path
```

This is why it's giving you an error.  It really shouldn't work if you're trying that in another project/file either -- unless your other project's `auth.__init__.py` is auto-loading its submodules.